# php how to walking through a 3-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

like walking through a 3-dimensional array of the following type:

```
$Marray = array(
        #string                 string          string
        'key1'      => array(   'value1'    =>  'title1'),
        'key2'      => array(   'value2'    =>  'title2')
    );
```

triying with this but not work this for each.

```
foreach($Marray as $key => $value => $title){
    echo $key." => ".$value." => ".$title."<br>";
}
```

i need get the 3 text field of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use two foreach loop as follow

```
foreach($Marray as $key => $val){
    foreach($val as $value => $title){
        echo $key." => ".$value." => ".$title."<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 foreach loops.  Try:

```
$output = [];
foreach($Marray as $key => $value){
    foreach ( $value as $subKey => $subValue ){
        $output[] = [$key, $subKey, $subValue];
    } 
}
var_dump($output);
echo $output[0];
echo $output[1];
echo $output[2];
```

The syntax you are attempting is not valid.  But the `$value` from the first loop is the `array` being processed in the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

Even simplier, with a single `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($Marray as $key => $val){    
    echo $key." => ". key($val) ." => ". current($val) ."<br>";
}
```

The output:

```
key1 => value1 => title1
key2 => value2 => title2
```